# After click view not display on screen if I set visibility to VISIBLE - Android

Tags: android

I got a view and in xml it is visible

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Then I do some manipulation with the data and I make it to invisible

```
container.visibility = INVISIBLE
```

But I have reset button that suppose to set the container back to visible after click

```
resetBtn.setOnClickListener {
        this.runOnUiThread { // tried this from stack overflow answers
            container.visibility = VISIBLE
        container.invalidate()} // tried this from stack overflow answers
    }
```

But after click I still do not see that container appears. What might be the issue?

Comment: What is in the container itself?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, be sure that resetBtn is referred to exactly your desired XML file. it's better to use view binding instead of kotlin synthetic.

then try one of these lines in your click listener:

```
container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
or
container.isVisible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put log inside setOnClickLitener to check whether click works or not.If log message does not appear, it means you have problem with button

Comment: click works fine...